# Native Advanced Ads doesn't work with Test AdUnit Ids?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

We have implemented IOS native Ads, here is the link to the code and steps we followed.
[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native-advanced) and
Github Sample
[Github Sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob/NativeAdvancedExample) Developers Documentation
We are using the following adUnit IDs:

```
let adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"
```

And

```
let adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4270592515"
```

Let me clear, both of these IDs work, but one in a ten time test. Mostly we get the warning, with no Ads to show: 
Invalid Request Response 
No Ads to show

Please reply us as soon as possible, will be really appreciating for us.

Comment: Immediately after installing AdMob and creating adUnitID, ads can not immediately display. Please wait 24 hours and try again

Comment: Thats for real Ads. We are using test adunit ids from the last 15 hours.

Comment: are you testing it on simulator or actual device? sometimes you get with simulator above 8.0.

Comment: capture traffic between your device and server and share those logs